# Can Postmaster update custom fields after sending emails?

Tags: add-on, custom-fields, postmaster

Is it possible to make Postmaster update an entry's custom field after it sends an email? I've got a custom field called 'Email Sent' and it'd be nice to stick a 'yes' in there for peace of mind once the email had gone out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a great idea. Currently there are no hooks or settings in place to do that.

I could also see a setting in place to store the number of times an email has been sent (for re-occurring emails). That way, you could say do not send after X times.

I will add this to the list of features to implement. If you need this immediately, I am available for an hourly rate of course. Email support[at]objectivehtml.com if you need such services.

Comment: Thanks for taking the idea on board Justin. It's only a 'nice to have' for me at the moment so I don't have a pressing need for it. But if that changes before such a feature is ever released, I'll be sure to get in touch via email.

Answer (score 1):

StackExchange still isn't allowing me to add comments, so I'm doing this as an answer.

A possible workaround is to add a hidden field to the form that sets the value in the custom field. This isn't the same since it will be set before the email goes out, but at least it's something.